# Selenium Web Driver Ruby Autocomplete text field

Tags: ruby, selenium, autocomplete, textfield

I am using Ruby to automate Web browsers.

I came across an issue while selecting one item from list from a 'AutoComplete' field.

For Example:
From google.com when you enter some text say 'he'. I would like to select 1 item from the suggestions provided.

I saw on stack suggestions to use by tag_name
tag_name is deprecated in latest selenium webdriver.

Java eqvivalent is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

String textToSelect = "headlines today";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
autoOptions.sendKeys("he");

List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
    System.out.println(option);
    if(option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
        System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write the Ruby equivalent of what you have written, but before that, I don't see the list is popping up when you write through send_keys, it's popping up only when you write manually and also there are many empty list are printing before you get some meaningful words

I have written the below code to know the index

```
@driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.co.in/")
@driver.find_element(id: "lst-ib").send_keys 'he'
sleep 4
@driver.find_elements(tag_name: "li").each_with_index  do |value,index|
  puts value.text + index.to_s
end
```

And I have gotten this output, remember since list is not popping up, I put sleep statement there, so you just manually press the space bar there as soon as it types 'he' in the text box. So you get the following ouput

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
he man20
he like that lyrics21
he is22
he ram he ram23
he like that24
he durga maiya25
he is my everything lyrics26
he has or have27
he for she28
he ne laser29
30
Report inappropriate predictions31
```

So 1 to 19 no words are found, therefore I click the 20th word in the below code

```
@driver.find_elements(tag_name: "li")[20].click
```

Comment: Does find_elements by (tag_name) works. I tried this, seems it is deprecated in latest selenium.

Comment: @SabhapathiA   No, it works! I used the recent selenium, it works. Since you decided to take Ruby Selenium Binding, I suggest you to use WATIR, it's a nice framework wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding, Timings are not depended on driver, it's maintained on local language bindings and syntax are easier.

Comment: @Sabhapathi If so can you accept my answer? There is a tick in  the left top of my answer that you need to click to accept my answer.